# SQL - insert data from two tables (or two rows from one) into third table PLUS specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

**Table 1: First**

```
id   name
1    Alpha
2    Beta
```

**Table 2: Second**

```
id   name
1    Charlie
2    Delta
```

**Table 3: Relations**

```
id   child_id   parent_id   belongsToFirst
```

So I'm struggling with the following concept:

I want to create a table that holds the parent-child relationship between two different tables. So when Alpha is Delta's parent the third table will hold data like so:

```
id   child_id   parent_id   belongsToFirst
1    2          1           0
```

The `belongsToFirst` will be 1 if the child_id is part of the 'First' group and zero if it is not. This value (0 or 1) will be set in the back-end code so it's not that important to the question except for that it needs to be in the query.

Now where I struggle is that child/parent relationships are possible within the first group as well. So Beta could be the parent to Alpha. This will be defined in the back-end code that will eventually render the query so SQL doesn't need to tackle finding out the relationship but it needs to be able to select two IDs from the same table.

In psuedo-code this would be:

```
Insert into Relations (child_id, parent_id, belongsToFirst)
Select id From (First or Second table) Where name='givenname'
And also
Select id From (First or Second table) Where name='givenname'
And lastly add value (0 or 1) to belongsToFirst
```

The `First or Second table name` would be generated by the code on the back-end (not in SQL) as well as `givenname` and the `belongsToFirst` value, but the query should still work if both entries are from the same table.

Can anybody help me out please? I've been bashing my head against the wall trying UNIONs but this stuff is going over my head at the moment. Thank you

Comment: First I might recommend a view for this. Also you should explain how to know if the parent is in table 1 or two and what field is the join key.  From what you posted I think you need joins not unions.

Comment: It's not handled in the SQL, You build the hierarchy in the front-end (for example PHP will render the table name in the From clause). So the front-end will pass that knowledge to the model which will render it in a query. It's just that the query should work in all hierarchy cases (Item from First being parent to item from Second, Second to First, First to First or Second to Second).